# validar datos de formulario laravel

Tags: laravel, validación

Hola estoy tratando de validar el siguiente formulario que básicamente es un filtro que hago para luego buscar esos datos en una tabla llamada `'datos_superficies'`, por ahora quiero validar el campo superficie, en el cual necesito que el usuario no ingrese un valor mayor a un valor máximo que se encuentre en la columna `'sup_ha'` de la tabla mencionada anteriormente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé muy bien como hacer esto ya que soy nueva en *laravel*, pero llegué al validador que tiene *laravel*, para obtener el valor máximo de mi columna lo obtengo así:

```
$maxSup_ha=DB::table('datos_superficies')->max('sup_ha');
```

Según vi en la documentación tenía que hacer algo así:

```
$request->validate(['sup_ha' => 'Ite:400']);
```

Donde `Ite` según la documentación hace lo que quiero, que el valor sea menor o igual en este caso a 400...(https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-lte)

En mi vista tengo lo siguiente:

```
@extends('layouts.base')
@section('content')
   <br>
     <div class="card-header">
        Filtro de datos de entrada archivo pl
     </div>
     @if ($errors->any())
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
             @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                 <li>{{ $error }}</li>
             @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endif
```

Pero hacer todo esto me da un ERROR : `"Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateIte does not exist."`
Entonces, ¿como se usa esto? y, ¿cómo podría, en vez de colocar 400, colocar el valor de `$maxSup_ha`?

Uso *laravel* 5.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes tener en cuenta que el nombre de la regla de validación es LTE (con L en minúscula y no con i mayúscula. Por eso el error que te arroja sobre un método que no existe.

---

A continuación, las validaciones no son más que pares de cadenas estilo llave > valor, en un array normal, por lo cual puedes poner el valor que quieras, siempre y cuando cumplas con este formato.

En ese orden de ideas, simplemente obtienes el valor que deseas para reemplazar el 400, y lo unes al nombre de la regla de validación, para formar la cadena:

```
$maxSup_ha = DB::table('datos_superficies')->max('sup_ha');

$request->validate(['sup_ha' => 'lte:' . $maxSup_ha]);
```

Idealmente, debes garantizar que siempre haya un valor en caso que la tabla no tenga valores.